# Insert items from one database to another SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to copy items from one database's table named items to another database's table named items. I have a mysql script below, but it gives an error.

```
INSERT INTO walmart.items 
(title, location, created_at, updated_at, image_url, url, price) 
VALUES 
(
    SELECT title, location, created_at, updated_at, image_url, url, price 
    FROM warehouse.items 
    WHERE url LIKE '%walmart.com%'
);
```

I am fairly certain that this is mostly a syntax issue and that I have the logic correct. I have tried a few different configurations but keep getting a similar error.

Error recieved:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT title, location, created_at, updated_at, image_url, url, price FROM old_t' at line 1
```

In warhouse:

`desc items;`

outputs

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| title      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| location   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| image_url  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| url        | varchar(255) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| price      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

in walmart

`desc items;`

outputs:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| title      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| location   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| image_url  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| url        | varchar(255) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| price      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You're insert select is wrong:

```
INSERT INTO walmart.items (title, location, created_at, updated_at, image_url, url, price)
SELECT 
title, 
location, 
created_at, 
updated_at, 
image_url, url, 
price 
FROM warehouse.items 
where url LIKE '%walmart.com%';
```

Here is the reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 1):

Not a MySQL expert, but I think this should be:

```
INSERT INTO walmart.items (title, location, created_at, updated_at, image_url, url, price) SELECT title, location, created_at, updated_at, image_url, url, price FROM warehouse.items where url LIKE '%walmart.com%';
```

Basically what you had, but without the VALUES keyword.  That's what it would be in SQL Server, and I don't think it would be different for MySQL.

The VALUES keyword is used when you're putting in values manually rather than selecting from a table.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `VALUES` and it will be working